Are any 2 linear combinations of a set of linearly dependent vectors linearly dependent?
I am trying to prove whether the following statement is true or not: that if we have some linearly dependent vectors, any 2 linear combinations of  these vectors constitutes a linearly dependent set of vectors.
I have started by letting $c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n$ and $d_1v_1 + \cdots + d_nv_2$ be arbitrary linear combinations of an arbitrary set of $n$ vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$, where the $c_i$ and $d_i$ are scalars. Considering the sum of these 2 vectors, we have $(c_1 + d_1)v_1 + \cdots + (c_n + d_n)v_n$. Something I noticed in the way of simplification is that there exists an $i$ such that $v_i$ is a linear combination of the other $n-1$ vectors, so this sum can be expressed in terms of only those $n-1$ vectors. However, I didn't see any way to take this line of reasoning forwards towards this claim.
So I would appreciate an answer as to whether or not any 2 linear combinations of a set of linearly dependent vectors are linearly dependent, along with a proof. It is solely my curiosity which drives me to ask this question, as this statement makes intuitive sense to me yet I was unable to arrive at a proof of it.

This is not clear.  What is a linear combination of a set?  Let's say ${\vec v_i}, ,{\vec w_j}$ are two sets of linearly dependent vectors.  Then...what are you asking about them?

@lulu I am asking about about a single set of vectors, the linear combination of a set of vectors being a linear combination of the vectors in the set

Specifically, your statement "that if we have a some linearly dependent vectors, any 2 linear combinations of  these vectors constitutes a linearly dependent set of vectors. " is hard to parse.

I mean, let's say $\vec v_1, \vec v_2$ are independent and consider the set ${\vec v_1, \vec v_2,\vec v_1+\vec v_2}$  Those are dependent, clearly.  But the two vectors $\vec A=\vec v_1+0\times \vec v_2+0\times (\vec v_1+\vec v_2), \vec B=0\times \vec v_1+ \vec v_2+0\times (\vec v_1+\vec v_2)$ are independent.  Is that what you mean?

Please edit your post for clarity.  As it stands, either your desired claim is obviously false or you are asking something that isn't clear.

@lulu your example is indeed in line with the intention of my question, and does answer it by disproving the claim. Thank you.

You can stuff a set to make it linearly dependent. Consider $\mathbb R^2$ and the set $\{(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$. This is clearly linearly dependent but $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ is not.
Hope this helps. :)
